# How to compile PCAP programm without installation require for costumer

Tags: c++, compilation, pcap, tcpdump, winpcap

I want to compile my libpcap and winpcap based programms, but I noticed that other users also have to install WinPCAP among my programm. How can I compile all necessary files into one programm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

The long answer comes from some old [wisdom](https://www.winpcap.org/pipermail/winpcap-users/2006-November/001586.html) in a WinPcap mailing list:

> There is a way to make `packet.dll` and `wpcap.dll` static: rebuild them as
>   such.  You just sacrifice the ability to **do** anything, since all the
>   stuff in `wpcap.dll` requires `packet.dll`, and all the stuff in `packet.dll`
>   requires the kernel driver.  And the kernel driver won't exist without
>   the full winpcap installation.
>
> It includes (among other things) a kernel driver that cannot be transformed to a static library.
>
> There is *no* *way* on Windows to make a kernel driver part of a static
>   library.  (Or a `DLL`, for that matter.)  If the kernel driver is
>   required, then it's hard to get anything done without it.